# How to use wildcard in Windows command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, dos

I some animations, they are like this:

> /OP/
>   /OP/OP1/
>   /OP/OP1/OP1.rmvb
>   /OP/OP2/
>   /OP/OP2/OP2.rmvb
>   /OP/OP3/
>   /OP/OP3/OP3.rmvb
>   /OP/OP4/
>   /OP/OP4/OP4.rmvb
>   ...and more

I want to make it like

> /OP/
>   /OP/OP1.rmvb
>   /OP/OP2.rmvb
>   /OP/OP3.rmvb
>   /OP/OP4.rmvb

I tried

```
move \OP\*\*.rmvb \OP
```

It gave me error says

> The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I also tried

```
dir \OP\*
```

This shows all the folders

But if I try

dir \OP**

It gave me the same error.

Could anyone please help me?? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that a programming question? Requiring to do this on the command line?
Otherwise, I would just do a Windows Search *.rmvb, and drag'n'drop the result to the folder of your choice...